# Scale everything in a pygame program

Tags: python, pygame, scale

Is it possible to scale all the items of a pygame program?

I am running the AdvancedDemo from with pygame project:

http://www.pygame.org/project-PaintBrush-1280-.html

But it is too large for my resolution. Is it possible to scale everything that is displayed to fit on the screen, without having to transform all the objects individually?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your advance demo works, but you can [use](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale)

```
pygame.transform.scale
```

to scale down the resulting screen. This might be a bit slow though.